# Invalid Request when debuging on Android devide, Xamarin

Tags: android, json, xamarin, webrequest

I'm writing a project in Xamarin Forms, and today we try our app on Android device. And our request to googleAPI stop working. Here's code :

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" + position.Latitude + "," + position.Longitude + "&radius=1000&types=bar&sensor=false&key=APIKEY") as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RequestCompleted), webRequest);
```

and then :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
var r = new StreamReader(stream);
var resp = r.ReadToEnd();
}
```

We got response and change it to json. On computer it works OK, but on Android it is saying INVALID REQUEST. Someone worked with Xamarin and know how to solve it?

Comment: Did you add the Internet permission in your project settings / android manifest?

Comment: Yeah, and in Android emulator everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I would have to guess, I'd guess, that the locale/ language on your phone is different to that one on your pc.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" + position.Latitude + "," + position.Longitude + "&radius=1000&types=bar&sensor=false&key=APIKEY") as HttpWebRequest;
```

There are implicit `ToString()` at `...n=" + position.Latitude + "," + position.Longitude + "&ra...` that produce a localized output. But the google API needs the values with a `.` as decimal separator.

Append `.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" + 
position.Latitude.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 
"," + position.Longitude.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
"&radius=1000&types=bar&sensor=false&key=APIKEY") as HttpWebRequest;
```